# insert if not exists mysql 5.5.24

Tags: mysql

I have been looking around, however i can not see my error,

My query

```
INSERT INTO p_location_check (location_id) VALUES (1) 
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT approved, disapproved FROM p_location_check WHERE approved REGEXP '^1234568745$' OR disapproved = '^1234568745$' AND location_id=1);
```

after just for testing

```
INSERT INTO p_location_check (location_id) VALUES (1) 
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT approved, disapproved FROM p_location_check WHERE approved = 1234568745 OR disapproved = 1234568745 AND location_id=1);
```

reponse

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT approved, disapproved FROM
>   qp_location_check WHERE approve' at line 2

server version

> Server version: 5.5.24-0ubuntu0.12.04.1

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to 'insert if not exists' in MySQL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1361340/how-to-insert-if-not-exists-in-mysql)

Comment: This is a job for `INSERT IGNORE` if location_id is a PK or unique key

Comment: it is, but not in mysql location_id  int(11) -- not unique `code`INSERT IGNORE INTO qp_location_check (location_id) VALUES (1) IF NOT
EXISTS (SELECT `approved` AS a, `disapproved`AS b, `user_id` FROM qp_location_check WHERE `approved` REGEXP '/^9846513213$/');

Answer (score 0):

**Edited:**

Try this query -

```
INSERT INTO p_location_check (location_id) VALUES (1) FROM dual
WHERE (SELECT COUNT(*)
       FROM p_location_check
       WHERE approved = 1234568745 OR disapproved = 1234568745 AND location_id=1
       ) = 0;
```

Add your WHERE condition.

Comment: Ok that worked (query didnt come up with errors, however it is not inserting anything) it should thought.

Comment: Also not sure what you doing with this part `code`ON t1.approved = t2.approved AND t1.disapproved = t2.disapproved AND t1.location_id = t2.location_id
  WHERE t2.approved IS NULL AND t2.disapproved IS NULL AND t2.location_id IS NULL`code`

Comment: No errors, but not insert, where is the insert VALUE ? or where should it go! `code`INSERT INTO qp_location_check(location_id)
SELECT DISTINCT(1) FROM qp_location_check t1
  LEFT JOIN (SELECT * FROM qp_location_check WHERE approved REGEXP '^1234568745$' OR disapproved REGEXP  '^1234568745$' AND location_id = 1) t2 ON t1.approved = t2.approved AND t1.disapproved = t2.disapproved AND t1.location_id = t2.location_id
  WHERE t2.approved REGEXP  '^1234568745$' AND t2.disapproved REGEXP  '^1234568745$' AND t2.location_id=1

Comment: I have changed solution completely. Try new one ;-)